# Decimal escape in a character class in a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, standards, pcre

Could somebody explain the semantics of a decimal escape inside a character class according to the ECMAScript standard ?

For example, what does the following pattern means ? Should it throw a syntax error ?

```
[\11]
```

Here are the relevant sections from the core specification:

- [21.2.2.19 ClassEscape](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-classescape)

  > The production ClassEscape::DecimalEscape evaluates as follows:
  >
  > 1. Evaluate DecimalEscape to obtain an EscapeValue E.
  > 2. If E is not a character, throw a SyntaxError exception.
  > 3. Let ch be E's character.
  > 4. Return the one-element CharSet containing the character ch.
- [21.2.2.11 DecimalEscape](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-decimalescape)

  > The production DecimalEscape::DecimalIntegerLiteral evaluates as follows:
  >
  > 1. Let i be the MV of DecimalIntegerLiteral.
  > 2. If i is zero, return the EscapeValue consisting of the character U+0000 (NULL).
  > 3. Return the EscapeValue consisting of the integer i.
  >
  > The definition of “the MV of DecimalIntegerLiteral” is in 11.8.3.
  >
  > - NOTE
  >     If \ is followed by a decimal number n whose first digit is not 0, then the escape sequence is considered to be a backreference. It is an error if n is greater than the total number of left capturing parentheses in the entire regular expression. \0 represents the  character and cannot be followed by a decimal digit.

There is also a mention of `ClassEscape` in the additional features for web browsers:

- [B.1.4.1 Pattern Semantics](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-regular-expression-patterns-semantics)

  > ClassEscape (21.2.2.19) includes the following additional evaluation rules:
  >
  > The production ClassEscape::DecimalEscapebut only if … evaluates as follows:
  >
  > 1. Evaluate DecimalEscape to obtain an EscapeValue E.
  > 2. Assert: E is a character.
  > 3. Let ch be E's character.
  > 4. Return the one-element CharSet containing the character ch.

My main issue is that I feel that the rule `DecimalEscape` only produces a character if it recognizes `0` (then it returns `U+0000`), otherwise it returns an integer, but I couldn't get a syntax error when testing with the Javascript console in Firefox.

Here are some results I found:

```
// This is the only one I understand:
/[\0]/.test("\x00") // true

// Now it gets strange
/[\1]/.test("\x01") // true
/[\2]/.test("\x02") // true
/[\3]/.test("\x03") // true
/[\4]/.test("\x04") // true
/[\5]/.test("\x05") // true
/[\6]/.test("\x06") // true
/[\7]/.test("\x07") // true
/[\8]/.test("\x08") // false
/[\9]/.test("\x09") // false
/[\10]/.test("\x0a") // false
/[\11]/.test("\x0b") // false

// This is not interpreted as `\1` and `0`
/[\10]/.test("0") // false

// Also, it's not a backreference
/((((((((((a))))))))))[\10]/.test("aa") // false
```

Why does it return `true` up to 7 and then `false` ? This shouldn't be related to octal. I would appreciate some clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/[\0]/.test("\x00")
...
/[\7]/.test("\x07")
```

returns `true` because the escaped integers are seen as numbers in octal notation *(base 8)*.

Obviously it isn't no more possible when you use 8 and 9 that aren't used in base 8. In this case the backslash is simply ignored.

```
/[\10]/.test("\x0a")
/[\11]/.test("\x0b")
```

return `false` since `\10` *(base 8)* gives 8 *(base 10)*.

```
/[\10]/.test("\x08")
/[\11]/.test("\x09")
```

will return `true`.

This behavior is part of the additional features for browsers (compatibility). The section [B.1.2 String Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-additional-syntax-string-literals) adds [`LegacyOctalEscapeSequence`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-annexB-LegacyOctalEscapeSequence) to the production rules of [`EscapeSequence`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-annexB-EscapeSequence). This rule defines the octal escapes `\0` up to `\377` for code units from 0 to 255.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that both Firefox and Node.js interpret _decimalEscape_ as octal. It goes up to `/[\377]/.test("\u00ff")` but then `/[\400]/.test("\u0100")` is false. For the moment it is just an observation, could you provide links to an authoritative source specifying this behavior ?

Comment: Found it: it is part of the browser additions (B.1.2), I edited your answer to include it.